# Spring-MVC does not call repository method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am fairly new, and trying to make a query on my local database but the code throws a `NullPointerException` exception.

It is weird as it looks like it never calls the selected method of repository called `findNamesByCat(String cat)`. It does not show  the output of `System.err.println("in repository");` that is located in this method.

Just after following line I called a method of another service and that works!!

```
 List<Name> Names = myService.findNamesByCat(cat);
```

**Error**

```
        Mar 18, 2015 1:29:07 PM 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
        ... threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
        java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.myproject.web.MyController.showCategoryNames(MyController.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Code**

```
@Controller
public class myController {

  @Autowired 
  private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cat}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showCategoryNames(@PathVariable String cat, Model model) {
        System.err.println("in web"); //shows this
        List<Name> Names = myService.findNamesByCat(cat);
        System.err.println(Names.size()); //this is line 41
        model.addAttribute("Names", Names);
        model.addAttribute("cat", cat);
        return "cat";
    }


@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Autowired
    private NameRepository nameRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Name> findListOfNamesByCat(String cat) {
        System.err.println("in service"); //does not show this
        return nameRepository.findNamesByCat(cat);
    }
}


@Repository
public class NameRepositoryImp implements NameRepository {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Name> findNamesByCat(String cat){
       System.err.println("in repository"); //does not show this
        try {
            Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(
                    Name.class);
            crit.add(Restrictions.eq("category", cat));
            return crit.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

**Servlet**

```
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject" />
```

### **UPDATE**

I made following changes as well but it does not work yet.

```
@Controller
public class myController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("repositoryService")
    private MyService myService;


@Service(value = "repositoryService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("repositoryMain")
    private NameRepository nameRepository;


@Repository(value = "repositoryMain")
public class NameRepositoryImpl implements NameRepository {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Comment: If you have a debugger capability in your IDE, use it to set blocks on key spots to see how far it goes. Fyi if your system.err output is set to file it may not be visible if you expecting it in console. I would also check if it makes it to findListOfNamesByCat in the service class.

Comment: @Aeseir I added a new system.err to service, it does not get to there.

Comment: Right so have you tried by putting in a value directly for cat variable? e.g.  List<Name> Names = myService.findNamesByCat("russian blue"); and see if it makes a call to the service or repository?

Comment: @Aeseir yes I added cat = "Jack" but it the same exception is thrown.

Comment: is it at least getting into the repository method? Coz it could be that its not either autowiring your repository, or the data doesn't exist in table.

Comment: @Aeseir it looks like the autowiring is not working coz it is not even showing the output of service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73291/discussion-between-jack-and-aeseir).

Comment: Take our readOnly in service and the exception capture in Repository. Something could be blowing up and we not seeing it. If that doesn't show something extra i want you to make these changes @Service(value ="repositoryService", @Respository(value = "repositoryMain". Then add qualifiers for each @Qualifier("repositoryService" and @Qualifier("repositoryMain") in the respective classes. Hope that makes sense. We are going to force them to autowire them up.

Comment: @Aeseir I removed readOnly and try catch in repository but same exception is thrown. This message is also shown Mar 18, 2015 1:40:55 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Comment: @Aeseir do you mean I should change @ Service to @ Service(value="repositoryService") etc? If thats what you mean i did it and it still throws same exception

Comment: You did it for @Repository too?

Comment: @Aeseir yes I put @Repository(value = "repositoryMain")
@Qualifier("repositoryMain") on repositoryImpl class and @Service(value ="repositoryService")
@Qualifier("repositoryService") on ServiceImpl class

Comment: No qualifiers go in the Controller class and Service class. I'll create answer and you can see, comment when you do so i can delete it.

Comment: @Aeseir whats your idea? I made all the changes but it does not work. The weird thing is that I have other repository and service classes that are working!

Comment: Nothing comes to mind immediately other than activate debugging in your IDE, put blocks at each line and see how far it gets you. You able to do that?

Comment: @Aeseir I did that but not sure if I did it right. It shows the variables get their values correctly, once it gets to List<Name> Names = myService.findNamesByCat(cat); easily passes it.

Comment: So the debug goes into the actual repository? Or skips those lines

Comment: The problem can't be the autowiring, since the default is 'required' and therefore if the autowiring could not be completed, Spring would be complaining on start up (and I am assuming it is not - @Jack?).

Comment: @Aeseir it just goes to List<Name> Names = myService.findNamesByCat(cat); and then goes to the next line.

Comment: @Jason so how to find out the cause of it?

Comment: The problem is not autowiring. The service method is returning a null. This then causes an NPE at Names.size() on line 41. You need to look at why your service method is returning a null.

Comment: @Jason it does not even print out the value of system.err of service method.

Comment: Sorry guys a funny thing is that I mistakenly put the system.err in another method with similar name, I confirm it gets to service method but the service method returns null.

Comment: Same problem with repository! really sorry for that. Tell me what to do with the answer for this question

Comment: Your best bet is to remove the question, given that it does not provide any help for future viewers.

Comment: @Jason I cannot remove it coz XLi posted an answer. I will flag it.

Comment: Then accept your own answer.

Comment: @Jason I already flagged it. Need to wait for two days to be able to accept my own answer. If they do not close it I will accept my answer in two days.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `@PathVariable String cat`, but didn't mark it correctly in `@RequestMapping`, add `{}` for PathVariable "cat", like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{cat}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: Sorry that is a typo, I voted your answer up for finding the typo. As I mentioned in the question it shows "in web" that is inside showCategoryNames method. I will update the question.

Comment: Is it a typo in this post or in your code? From log, the NullpointException happens in showCategoryNames(MyController.java:41), just before `System.err.println("in repository")`, so I guess it is also a typo in code. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: /cat was a typo in question, a typo in the code would not allow it to be executed.

Comment: @Jack, from your above comment, the call went through service method but returned null, right? If so, print out input "cat", and do a query directly in db to confirm if the record exists in db (category=cat).

Comment: @XLi the problem is solved, I mistakenly added the body of methods in wrong methods.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that, for some reasons the body of the methods that I was calling were empty and the correct bodies where replaced by body of other methods. After replacing the bodies and cleaning the project it started working. Thank you for your attempt to help and apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I cant, when I click on it to accept it, a message says cannot accept your own answer in 2 days.